# how to unfocus a textfield in flutter

Tags: flutter

im trying to create a textfield in flutter but when  you click or tap on it, i dont want it to gain focus. however, tap should work.

i have the following code

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: new TextField(
        focusNode: FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
         onTap: () {print 'test';}
      ),
    );
  }
```

FocusScope.of(context).unfocus() is given error
"the expression here has a type of  'void', and therfore can't be used"

i want to disable focus feature when you tap on the textfield but tap functionally should work and of course i dont want the keyboard to come up when tapping the textfield. any feedback ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [readonly](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/readOnly.html)
property, readonly will still gain focus and will block keyboard connection preventing it from popping up.

```
 TextField(
   readOnly:true
   controller: editingController,
   onTap: () async {
   selectedValue = await showDialog();
   setState(() {
      editingController.text = '$selectedValue';
    });
   },
 );
```

source :[issue:16863](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16863#issuecomment-522745415)

Comment: hi maheshmnj, thanks for the response.  read only works partially in that it hide the keyboard and dont focus but the problem is when i tap i will have a dialog box popup, user pick a value and the textfield will be set to a value.  user cannot change value, that is why i want to disable focus feature.  however, the textfield will be set with value when user pick a value from a popup dialog box.  how can i modify my code to disable on focus while still leave the text editable

Comment: In that case you can use the ```ontap()``` property of the textfield which shows the dialog and setState({}) on choosing the dialog to set a desired value to your textfield, keeping ```readOnly :true```

Comment: "will still gain focus"  so no, I will not try this